# AWS Lambda Timeout when making external HTTPS Request

Tags: java, aws-lambda, firebase-authentication, aws-api-gateway, firebase-admin

I need to use Firebase Admin Java in my AWS Lambda project, but Firebase Auth Admin throws a `SocketTimeoutException` when it tries to fetch a Public Key within the Google's servers. I know Firebase Admin is configured correctly, because I can run it locally in a Tomcat instance with no worries.

I tried then to just make an HTTPS Request to a test API like `https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2`, and it has the same behavior, I get a timeout as well, which leads me to think that this is a problem with Lambda invoking an HTTPS Request.

Now what I know:

1. My lambda is integrated with  API Gateway
2. My lambda is inside a subnet with internet access through an Internet Gateway
3. My lambda's Security Group is wide open
4. I know this problem happens on HTTPS Requests, I am not sure about pure HTTP. This is hard to test because I can't find an API out there that will not automatically redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, and I can't roll my own right now.

Just for the sake of completeness I will leave here the `SocketTimeoutException` I get from Firebase Admin Java, although I am not sure yet if this is a problem within the Firebase Admin library or with AWS Lambda + HTTPS or both together:

> [main] ERROR com.example.project.filters.FirebaseAuthenticationFilter
>   - Error while parsing or validating the token com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: Error while verifying
>   signature. at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.checkSignature(FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.java:160)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.verifyToken(FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.java:92)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$4.execute(FirebaseAuth.java:426)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$4.execute(FirebaseAuth.java:423)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.internal.CallableOperation.call(CallableOperation.java:36)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.verifyIdToken(FirebaseAuth.java:388)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.verifyIdToken(FirebaseAuth.java:362)
>   at
>   com.example.project.filters.FirebaseAuthenticationFilter.filter(FirebaseAuthenticationFilter.java:55)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:132)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:68)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:269)
>   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272) at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268) at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316) at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298) at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268) at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.jersey.JerseyHandlerFilter.doFilter(JerseyHandlerFilter.java:91)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.FilterChainHolder.doFilter(FilterChainHolder.java:84)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.AwsLambdaServletContainerHandler.doFilter(AwsLambdaServletContainerHandler.java:206)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.jersey.JerseyLambdaContainerHandler.handleRequest(JerseyLambdaContainerHandler.java:184)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.jersey.JerseyLambdaContainerHandler.handleRequest(JerseyLambdaContainerHandler.java:76)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxy(LambdaContainerHandler.java:177)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxyStream(LambdaContainerHandler.java:209)
>   at
>   com.example.project.StreamLambdaHandler.handleRequest(StreamLambdaHandler.java:39)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$StreamMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:350)
>   at
>   lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:888)
>   at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:293) at
>   lambdainternal.AWSLambda.(AWSLambda.java:64) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) at
>   lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:114) Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666) at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558) at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:264) at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367) at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
>   at
>   com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:104)
>   at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
>   at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GooglePublicKeysManager.refresh(GooglePublicKeysManager.java:172)
>   at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GooglePublicKeysManager.getPublicKeys(GooglePublicKeysManager.java:140)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.isSignatureValid(FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.java:226)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.checkSignature(FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.java:152)
>   ... 38 more

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> My lambda is inside a subnet with internet access through an Internet Gateway

An Internet Gateway alone will not provide a Lambda function residing in a VPC access to the Internet. This is because Lambda functions inside a VPC do not receive public IP addresses. You have to use a NAT Gateway to provide Internet Access to a Lambda function inside a VPC.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I found this some hours a go running a simple Lambda for testing this issue... What I am searching now is if there's anyway around using a NAT, I really don't what to pay $32 a month, I have a small project and here in Brazil that's expensive.

Comment: If your Lambda needs to access resources inside your VPC, and resources on the Internet, there is no way around using a NAT.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... Thanks

Comment: You could configure an EC2 instance as a NAT Instance instead of using Amazon's NAT Gateway, which might be cheaper although it would require more management, and you would need to configure it in an auto-scaling group or something in order to handle disaster recovery automatically.

Comment: I found out AWS actually provides an EC2  instance image ready to be a NAT, it appears to be 3x cheaper for a t2.micro, so I will probably go with this option for now at least.

Comment: this might help https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Comment: I have lambda that is deployed in VPC in public subnet. It needs a docker container access on EC2 instance. All good. But same lambda is trying to make a call to bedrock service which timeouts. When I remove VPC configuration the bedrock request is working fine. I created outbound rule to lambda security group that allows access to any domain over internet. Is this the same problem?

Comment: @user732456 your problem is exactly the same as the problem on this page, and the solution is the one I posted above in my answer.